# How to get value based on another value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of id's and numbers:

```
df_id =  id|values
         11|100
         22|109
         33|400
         44|90
         55|1000
```

I also have a dataframe that has id and age like this:

```
df =  id|age
      11|23
      22|21
      33|25
      44|20
      55|30
```

I want to get the age values from the second dataframe based on the id of the first dataframe, so it'd be: 11 is 23, 22 is 21, ...?

I have tried to query and read about it, but I don't know how to implement it exactly

Comment: join dfs on id?

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it.

Comment: What output are you trying to get? `df_id` with the `age` column joined to it, or just the `age` column selected by the `df_id` index? Please [edit] to clarify. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: @lone_ranger is there a different way of doing it without merge?

Comment: 1) why without merge, it is just the obvious way. 2) you still didnt answer @wjandrea what your output shoud look like. do you want a df, or just one single list of values.

Answer (score 1):

##### Approach without merge (not suggested)

This is a pure pythonic approach, but not suggested due to inefficiency.

```py
def splitBar(strValue):
  return strValue.strip().split("|")

with open("df.csv") as f:
  f.readline() # to remove the first line
  df = f.readlines()
  df = list(map(splitBar, df))
  idDf = [x[0] for x in df]
  age = [x[1] for x in df]

with open("df_id.csv") as f:
  f.readline() # to remove the first line
  df_id = f.readlines()
  df_id = list(map(splitBar, df_id))
  idDf_id = [x[0] for x in df_id]
  value = [x[1] for x in df_id]

[[id,value[index], age[index]] for index, id in enumerate(idDf_id) if id in idDf]
```

##### Output

```
[['11', '100', '23'],
 ['22', '109', '21'],
 ['33', '400', '25'],
 ['44', '90', '20'],
 ['55', '1000', '30']]
```

Note that, I assumed the name of the files you are dealing with are `df.csv` and `df_id.csv`. Also, note that the output matrix has three columns: the first one is the id, the second is the values and the last one is the age.

##### Merge approach (suggested)

If you are using pandas module, you should consider using `merge` function:

```py
df_id.merge(df, on="id")
```

Comment: is there a different way to do it without merge?

Comment: @mouhamad Of course, but please mention how you want the approach to be. Do you want to use pure pythonic approaches?

Comment: When this is a trivial merge, please close as duplicate to [merge 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101), **everything** is explained in details there.

Comment: @mozway Thanks for the comment. Seems it is not a trivial merge. So I will vote on the reopening the question and edit my answer to be pure pythonic script afterward.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani so what i saw online is using the query functionality but it didnt work well so either a pure pythonic approach or something like query would do the trick

Comment: This is a trivial merge and the duplicate provided non-merge alternatives.

Comment: @mouhamad the real question is, why don't you want to use `merge`? Is this an assignment?